# query database before 301 redirect PHP

Tags: redirect, header

I have some dynamic URLs that need 301 redirects.  Some of the new paths are stored in mysql.  So for instance,

```
index.php/comp/?view=product&id=50
```

will now redirect to

```
product/?view=product&id=50
```

Or depending on the id it could be

```
product/bags/?view=product&id=100
```

There is not enough info in the URL to perform a GET request to get the correct path.

Can I do a database query before doing

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.example.com'.$newpath);
```

There are thousands of these URLs and I don't want to have to resort to generating thousands of redirect via htaccess.

Comment: Have you tried running a test yet? Please post results if you do.

Comment: Hm. Yes, you can. I think it took more time to create this question than try for yourself.

Comment: I have some significant hurdles to jump before I can attempt this so I was hoping for some enlightenment before I try it.  I may just have to go ahead with it anyway if no answer is forthcoming.  If that is the case I will definitely post results here.

Comment: Good one, Tommi.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: So, for your understand, when server put task to your script, you can do anything your language is able to. It looks like your script doing redirect via http headers, but this is a script, this is a programming. You can do your redirect conditional, depending on _any_ thing: user id, current time, moon phase, random number. Just use conditional operators and put redirects into it.